# Summing rows above blank cell untill next blank cell and excluding rows from sum that do not meet criteria from another cell

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range, criteria

[image]I have a dataset which is separated by a blank rows.
I need to sum values in column C for all the rows above blank cell and exclude cell value from sum total if criteria in column A, B & T are met. And return the sum total value in the blank cell.

For example:
If column A = M, Column B = Buy and Column E = DAC then the Qty in column D for that row should not be considered while summing.

As you see in the image for Client A, row 1 is not considered in the total highlighted in yellow. Similarly for Client C, row 25 was not included in the total.

I found below code that worked beatifully to sum up values for all the rows above blank cell until next blank cell. But I am unable to add the criteria’s. I tried to use the Sumif/sumifs function but did not get the result.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub SumValues()
 
Dim FirstCell As Range
Set FirstCell = Range(“D2”)
 
Dim VeryLastCell As Range
Set VeryLastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, “D”).End(xlUp)

Do
    Dim LastCell As Range
    
    If FirstCell.Offset(1) = vbNullString Then
        Set LastCell = FirstCell
    Else
        Set Lastcell = FirstCell.End(xlDown)
    End if

    With LastCell.Offset(1, 0)
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(FirstCell, LastCell))
            .Interior.Color = RGB(253, 234, 123)
            .Font.Color = vbBlack
            .Font.FontStyle = “bold”
            .Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    End With

    Set FirstCell = LastCell.Offset(2, 0)

Loop While FirstCell.Row < VeryLastCell.Row

End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try with `SumIfs`?

Comment: Sumif(Range(”B2:B” & lastrow).End(xlUp), criteria, (Range(FirstCell, LastCell)))

Comment: Try this `Sumif(Range(”B" & FirstCell.Row & ":B” &  LastCell.Row), criteria, (Range(FirstCell, LastCell)))`

Comment: Did not work. Type mismatch.

Comment: I tried    SumIf(.Range(“B” & FirstCell.Row & “:B” & LastCell.Row), “criteria”, .Range(FirstCell, LastCell))    This did run the code but the all the sum values were 0

Comment: Don't use typographic quotes. Use double quotes ("). ASC=34 &H22